# Slug unique for another field different to the pub date?

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

im want to know if there is any way to make a SlugField unique for Any field different to pub date?

for example i would like a slug unique  (city field) for a field called country

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `unique_together` Meta option to your model class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    city = models.SlugField()
    country = models.SlugField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together(('city', 'country'),)
```

For more information, see the documentation on [`unique_together`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together).